# content provider & sqlite : sqlite error code=1 msg=column does not exist

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + NotePad.Notes.TABLE_NAME + " ("
               + NotePad.Notes._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
               + NotePad.Notes.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " TEXT,"
               + NotePad.Notes.COLUMN_NAME_NOTE + " TEXT,"

               + ");");
```

Guys,  I have the following problem.
04-05 16:40:09.773: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(1135): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: provider_value, db=/data/data/com.example.helloandroid/databases/note_pad.db

Here, COLUMN_NAME_NOTE has the value of provider_value. It still says the column does not exist.
Please let me know what the problem could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing your comma after the last `" TEXT,"`